# How to get Root Drive details using Windows API Code Pack?

Tags: c#, shell, windows-api-code-pack, shell32.dll

I wrote function which allows me to get all properties of any file.
This function even works for folders.

But I mentioned that without "Windows API Code Pack" and using "Shell32"  you can get early about 308 properties of any file.

```
        Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
        shell.NameSpace(@"C:\_test\clip.mp4").GetDetailsOf(null, i); // i = 0...320
```

However using "Windows API Code Pack" there is only 56 properties in "DefaultPropertyCollection" collection.
For example there is no "Rating" property in this collection.
Then I realized that instead of "shellFile.Properties.DefaultPropertyCollection" I should look into "shellFile.Properties.System"

```
    private void GetFileDatails(string path)
    {
        var shellFile = ShellFile.FromParsingName(path);

        textBox1.Text += shellFile.Properties.DefaultPropertyCollection.Count + "\r\n";
        shellFile.Properties.DefaultPropertyCollection.ToList().ForEach(el => textBox1.Text += el.Description.CanonicalName + "   -   " + el.Description.DisplayName + "   =   " + el.ValueAsObject + "\r\n");

        textBox1.Text += "\r\n" + shellFile.Properties.System.Rating;
    }
```

Yeas it is true!
But How can you get all other more then 200 properties of any files using this "shellFile.Properties.System"?
It is not even collection! It is not IEnumerable! You can not use foreach loop!
You should always type

```
      "shellFile.Properties.System.*"   //you should type this line more then 100 times
```

Anyway I can not get root drive details also!
Either using "Windows API Code Pack" or using "Shell32" 
I can not get "DriveFormat" of any partition! 
Please! tell me how to get "C Drive" details?

Comment: How to get "DriveType" property of any drive? Either is or not it "Fixed" type?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can use Reflection to enumerate all properties and get their values as following

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fileName = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "All Polished.mp4");
    ShellObject shellObject= ShellObject.FromParsingName(fileName);
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = shellObject.Properties.System.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
    {
        object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(shellObject.Properties.System, null);

        if (value is ShellProperty<int?>)
        {
            var nullableIntValue = (value as ShellProperty<int?>).Value;
            Console.WriteLine($"{propertyInfo.Name} - {nullableIntValue}");
        }
        else if (value is ShellProperty<ulong?>)
        {
            var nullableLongValue =
                (value as ShellProperty<ulong?>).Value;
            Console.WriteLine($"{propertyInfo.Name} - {nullableLongValue}");
        }
        else if (value is ShellProperty<string>)
        {
            var stringValue =
                (value as ShellProperty<string>).Value;
            Console.WriteLine($"{propertyInfo.Name} - {stringValue}");
        }
        else if (value is ShellProperty<object>)
        {
            var objectValue =
                (value as ShellProperty<object>).Value;
            Console.WriteLine($"{propertyInfo.Name} - {objectValue}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{propertyInfo.Name} - Dummy value");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```